# How can I get a divs left and right margin in pixels if the divs margin is set to auto?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, margin

`jQuery(".container").css("margin-right")` gives me: `auto`, while I want something like `52px` or `52`.

Comment: I had this exact problem about 5 minutes ago.. weird coincidence. Anon has given the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method calculates the remaining space between an elements width and the remaining width in the container, which is what `margin: auto` SHOULD do. This does NOT necessarily return the margin that the element has.

```
var parentwidth = $('.container').parent().width();
var childwidth = $('.container').width();
var marginLeft = (parentwidth-childwidth)/2;
```

NB: if there is any padding this must be compensated for.

Answer (score 3):

You can get parrent width subtracting the width of the current block and divide by 2

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(".container").offset()` to get the left position.
So, the left position of the current control minus(-) current control gives you the necessary output.